# Angular Reactive Form Individual Field Validation

Tags: html, angular, forms, typescript, reactive

When Validating a reactive form in Angular I want the error message to be displayed under the invalid field when an invalid data is entered.

```
<form  (ngSubmit)=sendQuery() [formGroup]="form">
  <div *ngFor='let key of modelKeys'>
    {{key}}
    <input name="query" placeholder="Enter {{key}} Here" formControlName="{{key}}" />
    <div *ngIf="(!key.untouched) || !(key.pristine) && !key.valid">
        Enter valid {{key}} detail
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" [disabled]='!form.valid'>Submit</button>
</form>
```

I always get the error messages displayed for all fields even if the field is valid. Why is the condition to display always true when the data is valid?

### Output

[image]

Environment:
Angular CLI: 7.1.3,
rxjs                              6.3.3,
typescript                        3.1.1

Comment: can you update modelKey json .. i got what is the probelm ...

Comment: I understand that key is a "string", so form.get(key) is the control. You must use < *ngIf="(!form.get(key).untouched) || !(form.get(key)..pristine) && !form.get(key).valid" />...< /div>,

Comment: please add .ts code, need to see that as well for debugging purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is here:

```
<div *ngIf="(!key.untouched) || !(key.pristine) && !key.valid">
  Enter valid {{key}} detail
</div>
```

`key` is just the (string?) key of your data and you are using it as a `FormControl` object, which obviously doesn't work. To use properties like `untouched`, `pristine` and `valid` you need to refer to a `FormControl`.

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-with-angular-v5-gnqcnv?file=app/app.component.html) is a quick stackblitz that shows how you could solve this.

Also I think your validation does not really work the way it is implemented currently, in the stackblitz I have implemented just a dummy validation that checks for the length of the string but it showcases how it works (only showing error message for the field that is actually invalid, e.g. length is 0).

And regarding your question why your error message always shows, this is because the condition `(!key.untouched) || !(key.pristine) && !key.valid` will always evaluate to true if `key` is a string. `'myKey'.untouched` will evaluate to `undefined`, which turns it into `!undefined`, which becomes true.

Comment: Yes it was a string. `form.get(key)` was what i needed. Thank you!!